# How to get Lat Long of tapped location in Google Map iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, cgpoint, cllocationcoordinate2d

I am trying to get the CLLocationCoordinate2D object from the tapped location in a google map view. But it always return me -180.0, -180.0 as lat,long like this:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -180.0, longitude: -180.0)
```

I am using following code for this:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
{
     let touchpoint = touches.first

     if let touch = touches.first
     {
        var point: CGPoint = touch.locationInView(self.view)

        let touchMapCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = MyMapView.projection.coordinateForPoint(point)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use following delegate method of `GMSMapView`.

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapAtCoordinate coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    println("You have lat and long")
}
```

Comment: Does this work in swift 3?  Because this doesn't ever trigger for me.

Comment: @Neo42 Looking at the documentation ( located at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38530470/how-to-get-lat-long-of-tapped-location-in-google-map-ios-swift ) yes, this should work for Swift 3. Do you have your `GMSMapView` delegate set?