# How do I get the Lat Long of where the user tapped? in Swift v3 and google maps sdk

Tags: swift, swift3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm coding an app in Swift3.  I'm using the google maps sdk.  I've implemented a GMSMapView.  I'm trying to ascertain what lat long that the user tapped in the GMSMapView.

Below is the reference for the android development version of what I think would help.  But I can't find the equivalent for iOS.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener

edit: The "possible duplicate" didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Lat Long of tapped location in Google Map iOS Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38530470/how-to-get-lat-long-of-tapped-location-in-google-map-ios-swift)

Comment: It's not a duplicate because I'm talking about Swift version 3 and the latest version of google maps SDK.  I tried the solution in the possible duplicate you mentioned but it never seems to trigger.

Comment: The API is indeed the same: [GMSMapViewDelegate](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p.html#a9f226252840c79a996df402da9eec235). Have you read the comment below the answer? *Looking at the documentation yes, this should work for Swift 3. Do you have your GMSMapView delegate set?*

Comment: Now.  Looking at your comment, I understand what you're asking.  "Do you have your MapView delegate set?"  You're right.  I didn't.  But I didn't know what to set it to or what you meant.  Some aspects of hooking in controls and UI can be easy to forget.

Comment: If I may make a suggestion, if you didn't know how to do or what was meant, that's a perfect time to ask a question in a followup comment. This is a Q&A site after all. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution at: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/events
by googling for didTapAtCoordinate, which I somehow knew was part of the SDK.

The most important line for me was:  **mapView.delegate = self**.  It's possible that some other solutions I tried would have worked had I used **mapView.delegate = self**, but nothing else had mentioned it.  Also, the  **func mapView** is of course important so I can use the coordinates of where the user tapped.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

override func loadView() {
  let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 1.285,
                                        longitude: 103.848,
                                        zoom: 12)

  let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera: camera)
  mapView.delegate = self
  self.view = mapView
}

// MARK: GMSMapViewDelegate
class DemoViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        print("You tapped at \(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)")
}//end func
```